# How do attatched property instances be gabage collected in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, memory, garbage-collection

Attached properties are designed to extend the dependency object,but how does the property value be stored in memory with one line code SetDPProperty(DependencyObject d) being related with the target object attached to?If it is stored in somewhere statically,and how can the AP check whether the target object is being used,and remove the reference in order to let GC collect if it is not?

Comment: It is stored exactly like a regular dependency property, and will be collected together with the DependencyObject it was set on.

Comment: I've seen the source code[link](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#WindowsBase/Base/System/Windows/DependencyProperty.cs,07f94fed9b1a6d52).you're perfectly right:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Values of dependency properties (including attached dependency properties) that have been set are stored internally in the `DependencyObject` base class and will be collected as usual whenever the object itself is collected. There is nothing special about these values when it comes to garbage collection.

If you want to know the details of how the values are being stored, you could take a look at how the `DependencyObject` class and its `SetValue` method is implemented here: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#WindowsBase/Base/System/Windows/DependencyObject.cs,76dfd12a4655a37a

There is nothing special about these values when it comes to garbage collection.